# data.frame with unconventional column names

Tags: r, tibble

```r
> data.frame(`(--fds` = 4)
  X...fds
1       4
```

Is there a way to get `data.frame` to have unconventional names like the above?

i.e.:

```r
> tibble(`(--fds` = 4)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  `(--fds`
     <dbl>
1        4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `check.names` argument in `data.frame`, set it to `FALSE`.

```
data.frame(`(--fds` = 4, check.names = F)
  (--fds
1      4
```